# generate date range per year basis

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle11gr2, oracle11gr1

I want to generate date range between trunc('7/1/2014','mm/dd/yyyy') and trunc(sysdate-1)+0.99999 (from 7/1/2014 till yesterday midnight) per year basis.

please refer to the attached image for expected result (https://i.stack.imgur.com/UD4Ub.png)

Comment: What issue are you having? What have you tried so far? There isn't anything for us to help you with at the moment, although I will say you don't want to add 0.99999. Just use two separate filters so you don't have to do terrible things trying to subvert the inclusiveness of BETWEEN.

Comment: There is no attached image.

Comment: I tried to add expected result as image. But it is not being added

Comment: Please check the link for the expected result image  https://i.stack.imgur.com/UD4Ub.png

Comment: Are you sure that's the way you need the output? It is very rare that the intervals should be from July 1 2014 to July 1 2015 and then from July 2 2015 to July 2 2016 and then from July 3 2016 to....   Much more common is July 1 2014 to June 30 2015, then July 1 2015 to June 30 2016, then July 1 2016 to ...

Comment: Yes That is the expected result. I need to pull data based on these date ranges. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Something like this. Adapt as needed. You probably won't `select * from ranges` but instead you will use the ranges wherever/however you need them. The input date `dt`, selected from a table `input_date` in my solution, may instead be a bind variable in your application, etc. Hope you are able to figure out the adjustments yourself; if not, please write back.

```
with
     input_date ( dt ) as (
       select to_date('07/01/2014', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
       from   dual
     ),
     ranges ( date_from, date_to ) as (
       select add_months(dt, 12 * (level - 1)) + level - 1,
              least(trunc(sysdate), add_months(dt, 12 * level) + level - 1)
       from   input_date
       connect by add_months(dt, 12 * (level - 1)) + level - 1 <= trunc(sysdate)
     )
select * from ranges
;

DATE_FROM   DATE_TO
----------  ----------
07/01/2014  07/01/2015
07/02/2015  07/02/2016
07/03/2016  11/28/2016
```